# How to solve $2^x=2x$ analytically.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$2^x=2x$$
I am able to find the solutions for this equation by looking at a graph and guessing. I found them to be $x_1=1$ and $x_2=2$.

I also can also find them by guess and check, but is there anyway algebraically to solve this problem?

Comment: This has no solution that you can find algebraically. We need to use the [Lambert W-Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html).

Comment: Clearly $2^x>2x$ for all $x>2$.

Comment: Also clearly $x>0$, because $2^x>0,\forall x\in\Bbb R$. So if $2^x=2x$, then $x\in(0,2]$.

Comment: your title asks for an analytical solution, while your questions asks for an algebraic approach. Which do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x-\log_2(x)-1$, which is the difference of the logarithms of the two members.

The derivative is $$1-\frac1{\ln(2)x},$$ which has a single zero for $x=\dfrac1{\ln(2)}$.

As there is a single extremum, there cannot be more than two roots, which you found.

---

There is no closed formula for these roots, except using the Lambert function. Isolating the roots in monotonic intervals so that they can be refined by numerical methods can/should be considered a valid algebraic solution.

Comment: This is valuable, but in essence a "guess and check" method enhanced by a proof that there are no solutions other than the "guessed" ones (evident on a graph).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: you didn't get the point. The method relies on finding monotonic sections of the curve, which can only feature a single root. When these sections present a change of sign, a root is guaranteed. For brevity I omitted to say that the extremum is a negative minimum and the function grows to infinity on both sides, but this is easy to show. The exact location of the roots is just a bonus.

Comment: I am slightly confused on how this solves the above function.  Yes, $f'(x)=1-\frac 1 {\ln(2)x}$, but how does help me solve the question?  I don't believe there to be a single zero at $x=\frac 1 {\ln(2)}$ but rather a single extremum as you stated.  There could have been roots where $f'(x)$ does not equal 0.  Note: $\frac 1 {\ln(2)}=\log_2(e)$  If I were to try to substitute this "solution" back into $f(x)$, it should produce $f(x)=0$, which it does not.  Rather, it gives $\log_2-\log_2(\log_2(e))-1$, which can be seen not to equal 0.  The OP was asking for $2^x=2x$, which should mean $f(x)=0$

Comment: @SimpleArt: the roots of the derivative are used to find the extrema, and the monotonicities between them. This is called root isolation.

Comment: :)  Thank you.  I've never actually done that till I made my post, all the way at the bottom...

Answer (score 6):

Not without using the [Lambert $W$ function](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), which is really just a fancy reformulation of the problem, and not actually a solution.

Comment: Well, it *is* a solution, because a lot of work has been done on computing it, and you can get routines that do that quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Well there exists analytical way. Here is my method.
Firstly divide by 2 both sides to obtain $2^{x-1}=x$. Now let's construct the function : **$f(x)=2^{x-1}-x$**. The first derivative of which is $f'(x)=ln2*2^{x-1}-1$. And the second derivative of which is $f"(x)=(ln2)^2*2^{x-1}$.

Now we can easily see that for all $x \rightarrow f"(x)>0$. So it follows that $f'(x)$ is increasing for all $x$. If for $x=2$ $f'(x)>0$, then for all $x>2$ $f(x)>0$.

And that means for $x\ge 2$ the function $f(x)$ is increasing. Since $f(2)=0$ that means there is no root greater than 2.

In the same way we have that for $x\le 1$, $f(x)$ is decreasing. since $f(1)=0$ that means there is no root smaller than 1.

Also the rest is easy to show that between 1 and 2 there is no root.

Comment: While valuable, this method is again a "guess and check."  After all, we are told that $f(2) = 0$, but not how we *found* that value, $x=2$.

Comment: Maybe you are right to some point  but though still with derivatives you get rid of guessing for more solutions. One can guess those 2 solutions but  cant guess if there is no other solution except of those 2. In this case derivatives solve the maze.

Comment: The poser asks explicitly:  "...is there anyway algebraically to solve this problem?"  Nobody has answered that question, except to point to the Lambert W function.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=2^x-2x \\
f'(a)&=\ln2\cdot e^a-2\\
a&=\ln(2\ln2)\\
f'(a)&=2\ln2-2\ln(2\ln2)=2\ln\frac{1}{\ln 2}<0
\end{align}$$
Therefore $f'$ has two roots.
So, $x=1$ and $x=2$ are only roots.

Answer (score 0):

Despite noting that an answer has already been chosen, I will attempt to show how problems like these are solved with the Lambert W function.$$2^x=2x$$$$1=\frac{2^x}{2x}=\frac 1 {2x}2^x$$Power everything we have by $-1$:$$1=1^{-1}=(\frac 1{2x}2^x)^{-1}=2x*2^{-x}$$From here, we attempt to make the exponent and coefficient the same with base $e$.$$1=2xe^{-x\ln(2)}$$$$\frac 1 2=xe^{-x\ln(2)}$$$$-\frac 1 2 \ln(2)=-x\ln(2)e^{-x\ln(2)}$$Now we can apply the Lamber W function, which is:$$y=W(ye^y)$$In other words, $y=-x\ln(2)$.  This gives us:$$W[-\frac 1 2 \ln(2)]=W[-x\ln(2)e^{-x\ln(2)}]=-x\ln(2)$$Now divide by $-\ln(2)$:$$x=\frac{W[-\frac 1 2 \ln(2)]}{-\ln(2)}$$.

Which, amazingly, should have solutions $x=1$ and $x=2$.

This is closest to $algebraic$ that you can do when given functions, one an exponential and one a polynomial (yes, you can do it for polynomials and even rational functions) and told they are equal to each other.

Also, if you had come upon, say, $10^x=x$, you would note that, graphically, the two lines do not cross.

However, with the Lambert W function, you can find the solution regardless if the graphs touch because the Lambert W function can be extended to complex and imaginary numbers.

I will also not the above examples as possible methods to solving your question with the use calculus.

In a nutshell, they found that a function $f(x)$ that equals zero.  You get this $f(x)$ as follows:$$2^x=2x$$$$\log_2(2^x)=\log_2(2x)$$$$x=\log_2(2*x)=\log_2(2)+\log_2(x)=1+\log_2(x)$$$$x=1+\log_2(x)$$$$x-\log_2(x)-1=0=f(x)$$Then we attempt to find $f'(x)$, the function that is the slope of $f(x)$ for any value $x$.$$f'(x)=1-\frac 1 {x\ln(2)}$$There are methods to finding this function when you learn calculus, so I won't elaborate.

The reason we solved for $f'(x)$ is so that we can find where the slope is zero.  This is helpful, for imagine a circle.  It has a slope of zero at the top and bottom.  Now imagine a polynomial.  It has a slope of zero at the tops and bottoms of all its curves.  This can be helpful for finding things like your solution.

In particular, we are finding $f'(x)=0$.$$0=1-\frac 1 {x\ln(2)}$$$$1=\frac 1 {x\ln(2)}$$$$x=\frac 1 {\ln(2)}$$

Now, let's find $f''(x)$, the second derivative of $f(x)$, or the slope of $f'(x)$.  We can use this to determine if a graph bends up or down.$$f''(x)=\frac 1 {x^2\ln(2)}$$For all $x$, $f''(x)$ is positive.  This means it always bends upwards.

Also, we have proven that the graph has a slope of zero at $x=\frac 1 {\ln(2)}$.  This means that from this point on, the graph goes up.  It has a "U" shape.  The bottom of this "U" is at $x=\frac 1 {\ln(2)}$.

Also recall that we are trying to find $f(x)=0$.

So from all of this, we have the following:

1) $f(x)=0$ happens at the x-intercepts.

2) $f'(x)=0$ is the bottom of our "U" shaped graph.

3) $f''(x)>0$, meaning it will always bend up in a "U" shape.

From this, I deduce that I should probably find $f(x)_{bottom.of."U"}$.  I know this occurs at $x=\frac 1 {\ln(2)}$, so I simply plug that into my $f(x)$ formula.$$f(\frac 1 {\ln(2)})=\frac 1 {\ln(2)}-\log_2(\frac 1 {\ln(2)})-1$$If this is negative, then my $f(x)$ function will go up (in a "U" shape) and hit the x-axis.  Where it hits the x-axis is your solution, if and only if $f(\frac 1 {\ln(2)})<0$.  Otherwise the "U" will never touch the x-axis.

And using a calculator, we see that it is in fact negative.

Which means we just proved the solution's existence (Meaning the solution is not imaginary or complex).

So what now?  This probably hasn't helped you much, but now that we see this exists, I would recommend Linear Approximation.  Sadly, there is no algebraic method to solving your problem from here.  If you want to attempt Linear Approximation, you go right ahead, because it is too tedious for my answer.  If you don't understand it, try youtube or a different Linear Approximation method because some methods are easier than others.

P.S.

Also, as a bonus, you already know what $f(x)$, $f'(x)$, and $f''(x)$ are.  Just look for them in my post.  Most linear approximation methods require those formulas.  I believe my functions have also already met all requirements for you to start attempting to use Linear Approximation, e.g., $f(x)=0$.

Simply and with much pleasure,

Simple Art.

Comment: Would newton's method be a good linear approximation? By knowing that at $x=\frac{1}{ln2}$  there is a local minimum and that it is below the x-axis one knows there are 2 roots. This is all correct? Doesn't the Lambert W function use newton's method for its calculation? Would this make using newton's method on this function the same as using a Lambert W function in principle?

Comment: Well, we have calculators that calculate the Lambert W function (yeah, probably using approximation methods).  This is indeed all correct, as you can see using graphs.  Newton's method would be a good linear approximation, but it doesn't always work.  Sometimes, some linear approximation methods may not work, but there are plenty that should.  If newton's method seems to produce stranger and stranger answers, it is probably going to go nowhere.